# What happens when we pass int arguments to the overloading method having float as a parameter for one method and another having double param

Tags: java, oop, overloading

In overloading concept, i am having one doubt, that is .
when i comes to overload the method with int value the method call's the float parameter method rather the double parameter method.

```
void method1(float f){
System.out.println('float');
}

void method1(double f){
System.out.println('double');
}
```

> method call:

```
method1(10);
```

> output: float

As stated in the java tutorials in this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) 
A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d.

For the above case the method call should call the double parameter method. But it call's float parameter method.

How the process of overloading taking place in this area?.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Testing a variant of your code, except with a `byte` literal and overloaded methods with various combinations of `short`, `int`, and `long` appears to imply that the compiler chooses the "least widening" conversion if more than one is available.

Thus:

- Between a `short` and an `int`, if you call the overloaded method with a `byte`, the `short` variant will be chosen
- Between an `int` and a `long`, if you call the overloaded method with a `byte` or `short`, the `int` variant will be chosen

And so forth.

Thus, because `long` can be widened to either `float` or `double`, and because the `float` conversion is the "least widening", the `float` overload is chosen.

---

I *think* this is because of the "choose the most specific overload" way that the compiler resolves multiple possible overloads. From the JLS, section 15.12.2.5:

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

So by this, a method that takes a `float` is "more specific" than a method that takes a `double` because any invocation handled by a method that takes a `float` can always be handled by a method that takes a `double`, but not the other way around.

Comment: The golden informations. Thanks for your supports to community.

Answer (score 8):

as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

> 5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion
>
> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> byte to short, int, long, float, or double
>
> short to int, long, float, or double
>
> char to int, long, float, or double
>
> int to long, float, or double
>
> long to float or double
>
> float to double

Comment: But why `float` over `double`? That list doesn't seem to specify "precedence" to me...

Comment: Precedence is about operators, not automatic conversion.

Answer (score -1):

In Java,there is relation between sub class and super class and also ascending level for primitives from byte short.... to double.

The rule is, whenever there is ambiguity which overloaded method to choose, the most near one sub class overloaded method or nearest primitive in ascending order is chosen.