# Why Java's Math.round() cannot handle this number?

Tags: java, rounding

I have code like this:

```
System.out.println("Math.round(1423562400L) => " + Math.round(1423562400L));
```

And the result is this:

```
Math.round(1423562400L) => 1423562368
```

This value is a 64-bit integer but it easily fits inside a 32-bit integer which should fit in a double. What is going on?

Comment: It works when you cast to `(double)` first. Apparently, it is a `float` otherwise ?!

Comment: But why does a `long` get automatically cast to a `float`?

Comment: @swdev [JLS 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) tells that both float and double are applicable, and [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) tells float is the **most specific method**.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279680/what-happens-when-we-pass-int-arguments-to-the-overloading-method-having-float-a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5),

> **15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method**
>
> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

It follows that [`Math.round(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)) is more specific than [`Math.round(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)), and since they're both [valid overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293867/1553851), the compiler chooses the former, resulting in lost data.

To correct your output, simply change `1423562400L` to `1423562400d`.

Comment: Can you elaborate why `float` version is more specific than `double` version? So, it tries the float version first and if it compiles then it uses it. But why the float version first. That isn't specified in the JLS.

Comment: @swdev Read the second paragraph I quoted. It implies that the float version is more specific because a float can be passed as a double, but not vice-versa (without narrowing conversion).

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. This is weird behavior compared C++. In that language you would get the following `error: call of overloaded 'round(long int)' is ambiguous` passing an integer to a function with both float types defined.

Comment: @swdev: Yeah, ambigous overload error might have been the safer choice here. But that boat has sailed.

Comment: @swdev the concept of choosing the more specific overload makes sense to me personally. What was more surprising is that long to float is considered a widening conversion. But as discussed in the answer I linked, you can technically make the same argument about long to double.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Math.round()` has implementation which supports `long` argument. Here is the `Math.round()` signature.

```
Math.round(double a);
Math.round(float a);
```

`Math.round()` accepts `double` or `float`, So when you are passing `long` you are doing something like (`long` converts to float implicitly)

```
float x = 1423562400L;
System.out.println(Math.round(x));
```

To Solve this you can add your `long` value to `double` first and it will work like charm.

```
double x = 1423562400L;
System.out.println(Math.round(x));
```

To simplify you can do

```
Math.round((double)1423562400L)
```

or

```
Math.round(1423562400d)
```

Here is the picture that shows the how **implicit conversion** works and why **`long`** gets converted to **`float`**

[image]

Image source [here](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/ch1-javabasics-150827084618-lva1-app6892/95/chapter1-java-basics-11-638.jpg?cb=1440762023)

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. It's a waste of your time, which I don't care about, and our bandwidth, which I do care about. It also prevents copy/pasting into comments. It is basically pointless.

Comment: `long converts to float implicitly`. True, but long also converts to double implicitly (and without loss in this case). But here the "narrower" overload was chosen.

Comment: When conversion takes place. The hierarchy is followed. So first long will be converted to float as we have a round() which supports float.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that the signature of Math.round is

```
public static int round(float a)
```

it accepts a 32bit float, now you put a 64bit long to this method,
it cut the long to an int, and then turn it to a float.

```
System.out.println(Math.round((int)1423562400L));
System.out.println(Math.round((float)1423562400L));
```

the code prints 1423562368 too

if you convert it to double explitly
then the result is correct

1423562400

Comment: Well, there is also a `double` overload of the same method. One could have hoped that that one gets used instead.

Comment: @Thilo, Yes, this was my hope, too.