# In Java can I overload with float and int

Tags: java, overloading

If I want to have a method

```
void mymethod(float val) {}
```

and another one

```
void mymethod (int val) {}
```

then when I call `mymethod (1.2)` will it correctly detect the first one is the right one to call?

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when we pass int arguments to the overloading method having float as a parameter for one method and another having double param](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279680/what-happens-when-we-pass-int-arguments-to-the-overloading-method-having-float-a)

Comment: Read about [overriding vs overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374399/what-is-the-difference-between-method-overloading-and-overriding)

Comment: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/ seems to says it can looking at case 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mymethod(1.2)` will look for a `mymethod(double d)` method since literal `1.2` for an inlined numeric value is stored in a `double` by default.

You should write : `mymethod(1.2F)`

In this case, overloading will work and `mymethod(float val)` will be called.

Overloading allows to name multiple methods with the same name but with distinct parameters. At compile time, the compiler chooses the method which matches with effective parameters.

In your case, `mymethod()` method is overloaded since :

```
 void mymethod(float val) {}
 void mymethod(int val) {}
```

Comment: Okay I will try it