# How method-overloading and primitive types works?

Tags: java, overloading, primitive-types

I'm doing my Java class exercises. I have this code which contains an overloaded method:

```
class A {

    // Overloaded method
    public void f(int n, float x) {
        System.out.println("f(int n, float x) n = " + n + " x = " + x);
    }

    private void f(long q, double y) {
        System.out.println("f(long q, double y) q = " + q + " y = " + y);
    }

    public void f(double y1, double y2) {
        System.out.println("f(double y1, double y2) y1 = " + y1 + " y2 = " + y2);
    }

    public void g() {
        int n = 1;
        long q = 12;
        float x = 1.5f;
        double y = 2.5;
        System.out.println("--- dans g ");
        f(n, q);
        f(q, n);
        f(n, x);
        f(n, y);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    A a = new A() ;
    a.g() ;
    System.out.println ("--- dans main") ;
    int n=1 ; 
    long q=12 ; 
    float x=1.5f ; 
    double y = 2.5 ;

    a.f(n, q) ; // my problem is here
    a.f(q, n) ; 
    a.f(n, x) ; 
    a.f(n, y) ;  
}
```

When I call the method `a.f(n,q)` in main I expect an error, but it calls the method `f(int n, float x)` while my `q` is a `long` number and it's size is bigger then a `float`'s size (8 byte / 4 byte) So I wonder how these primitive types works?

Comment: `long`s can be converted to `float` no problem. But you'll lose precision. See 5.1.2 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html).

Comment: specifically, [5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Comment: Not exactly "no problem".  Some would consider the loss of precision a problem.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem "no problem" meaning "no compile- or run-time errors" :)

Comment: and this is allowed in phase 1 of overload resolution, see [5.3. Invocation Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), the part about "Strict invocation contexts".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when we pass int arguments to the overloading method having float as a parameter for one method and another having double param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279680/what-happens-when-we-pass-int-arguments-to-the-overloading-method-having-float-a)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Method invocations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) occupy a pretty length chunk of the spec. To summarize, the compiler proceeds as follows:

1. Identify classes on which the method might be invoked.
2. Identify methods on those classes which might be invoked.
3. If more than one method was identified, pick the most specific one.

Step 2 is the most interesting one here: this proceeds in a number of steps. To summarize:

1. If there is a non-varargs method on the class with the exact same parameter types (strict invocation), choose that.
2. If there is a non-varargs method on the class with parameter types for which automatic conversions from the actual parameters (loose invocation), choose that.
3. If there is a varargs method on the class with parameter types that match with automatic conversion, choose that.

You're supplying parameters that don't exactly match any of the parameter types of the overloads, so you need check if you can convert that parameters to allow strict invocation. The conversions in strict invocations [are](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3):

> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)

An `int` can be converted by identity conversion to `int`. A `long` can be converted by [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) to a `float`.

Hence `f(int, float)` is applicable.

`f(long, double)` and `f(double, double)` are also applicable, since `int` can be widened to `long` and `double`; and `long` can be widened to `double`.

However, these are less specific than `f(int, float)`, since `int` can be widened to `long` and `double`, and `float` can be widened to `double`. Hence, by the [informal intuition laid out in JLS Sec 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), these methods are less specific than `f(int, float)`. As such, `f(int, float)` is the one that is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

`longs` can be converted to `float` without raising errors. But you may lose precision.

For details see [the specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Comment: Thank you that's too quick, so it can be converted even that they have not the same size !?

Comment: As I said, yes, but you may lose precision, so you may not obtain numbers that are arithmetically equal to each other.

Answer (score -2):

The following 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:

byte to short, int, long, float, or double

short to int, long, float, or double

char to int, long, float, or double

int to long, float, or double

long to float or double

float to double

Widening primitive conversions do not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value.

...

Conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, may result in loss of precision-that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the long value.

Comment: At least put a link to where you copied this from, please.

Comment: I have copied from this site only. I search for this question and that matter help me to understand the problem. So, I thought this might help someone else too.

Comment: @AshishGoyal "I have copied from this site only." then you should link to where on this site you copied it from. Use the `[share]` link below an answer to get a direct link. [The licence on user contributions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109786/what-is-the-license-on-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers) is "cc by-sa 3.0 **with attribution required**".

Comment: @AndyTurner Even then, this is directly from the [specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) which have a different [license](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/spec-license.html) anyway.